# How can I consolidate all of my "setup code" away from my WebAPI controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

All of my controllers look like this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/businessname")]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateBusinessName(BusinessNameDto model) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        try {
            _userService.UpdateBusinessName(User.Identity.Name, model.BusinessName);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ApiResponseDto() {});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // logging code
            //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ApiResponseDto() { Success = false, Error = "Something bad happened :(" });

        }
    }
```

There's a *lot* of repeated stuff across my controllers.  Ideally I could just have this:

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/businessname")]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateBusinessName(BusinessNameDto model) {
            _userService.UpdateBusinessName(User.Identity.Name, model.BusinessName);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new ApiResponseDto() {});
    }
```

And tell WebAPI to do all that other stuff with every controller... but I don't know if that's possible.  How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca do the following:

1) Create a validation filter so that your action method executes ONLY if the model state is valid. So that you don't need to check ModelState.IsValid anymore in your action methods.

```
public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Create a exception handling filter which will catch any exception thrown by the action method, serialize it and create a HTTP BadRequest response message to the client. So that you don't have to use try catch anymore in your action methods.

```
public class HandleExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        responseMessage.Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message);

        context.Response = responseMessage;
    }
}
```

You can register these filters in WebApiConfig.cs by adding the below lines to it

```
config.Filters.Add(new ValidationActionFilter());
config.Filters.Add(new HandleExceptionFilter());
```

**UPDATE:** To be more specific to SB2055's scenario, i am adding the below code

```
public class HandleExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var model = new ApiResponseDto() { Success = false, Error = context.Exception.Message })
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            model);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to send a custom type down with Http.OK instead of Http.BadRequest, like I am in my current code?

Comment: In terms of syntax, how can I send a custom type?  My original syntax isn't working.

Comment: You create new ApiResponseDto() { Success = false, Error = context.Exception.Message } in the filter. Serialize it to json and send it back.

Comment: it seems crazy that I have to serialize that on my own, if only I could just include my object.  I'd like to wait and see if there's a better way before accepting, thank you for this though

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActionFilterAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). For example, to validate requests you can create a class similar to this:

```
public class ValidateRequestAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
   {
      if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState)
      }
   }
}
```

You could then selectively apply the filter to your Web API actions by decorating them with the attribute:

```
[ValidateRequest]
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/businessname")]
[Authorize]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateBusinessName(BusinessNameDto model) {
    ...
}
```

Or apply them to all your actions during Web API setup using `HttpConfiguration.Filters`:

```
config.Filters.Add(new ValidateRequestAttribute());
```

Comment: Cool.  What about wrapping every request in a try/catch?

Comment: Override the `OnActionExecuted` method in your filter and check the `HttpActionExecutedContext.Exception` property to determine if an exception was thrown. You can then set a response accordingly.

Comment: The other answer shows OnActionExecuting as opposed to Executed... would you mind providing a sample?